# SQL Filter options

Tags: sql, sql-like

I would like to see if I can isolate all the records where there is a `recordlocator` but not a word 'ticket' inside the `templatename` column

```
SELECT * FROM [Database]
WHERE SentDate BETWEEN '42002' AND '43000'
AND RecordLocator NOT LIKE ''
AND TemplateName NOT LIKE '%Ticket%'
```

So I would see all the records where recordlocator is not null and that recordlocator does not contain the word 'ticket'

But I am lost, one unique recordlocator is will appear in multiple rows and the templatename can have multiple values..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Btw: you select from a **table** not from a "database"

Comment: So you need to use a "NOT EXISTS" clause.

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (3) Explain why your query doesn't work.  It seems to implement the logic.

Comment: in some rdbms there is a difference between empty string and NULL so you might want to check if that's the case for you